# Извлечь текст из формы

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

Пользователь вводит коммент к статье в форму.

Задача отправить его на сервер ajax-запросом. Делаю следующим образом:

```
$('#postForm').submit(function(e){

$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "{% url 'advert' %}",
            data: {'text': $(this).serialize(), 'id': $(this).attr('name'), 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response) {
                $('#comments').append('<p>', response.message, '</p>');                            
            },
        }); 
e.preventDefault();
})
```

в объект `data['text']` попадает как `crsf-token` так и текст из формы.
Как сделать, чтобы там был только текст формы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#postForm').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var data = {};
    var url =  $('#postForm').attr("action");

    data['csrfmiddlewaretoken'] = $('#postForm [name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val();
    data['text'] = $('<ВАШЕ ПОЛЕ INPUT>').val();
    data['id'] = $(this).attr('name');


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: data,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
            $('#comments').append('<p>', response.message, '</p>');                            
        },
    }); 
})
```